# My form isn't submitting and I get no error

Tags: python, forms, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am creating an admin page. The admin creates all users and also has the right to edit and delete users.

Now I am having issue updating their image inside the form as when I click on the submit button the image in the database doesn't update and it doesn't show me any error it just loads the page.

I created another function called `picture_format()` that autogenerates a token of about 8 characters and i concatenate the extension with the generated token value and save it in a folder on the server.

**routes.py**

```
    def picture_format(form_picture):
       random_hex = secrets.token_hex(8)
       _, ext = os.path.splitext(form_picture.filename)
       picture_fn = random_hex + ext
       picture_path = os.path.join(app.root_path, 'static/pictures', picture_fn)
       img = Image.open(form_picture)
       img.thumbnail((125, 125))
       img.save(picture_path)
       return picture_fn
        
    def edit_user(user_id):
      user = User.query.get_or_404(user_id)
      form = UserUpdateForm()
      if form.validate_on_submit():
        if form.image_file.data:
         img_name = picture_format(form.image_file.data)
         user.image_file = img_name
         db.session.commit()
         user.username = form.username.data
         user.email = form.email.data
         db.session.commit()
         flash('User Account Updated Successfully', 'success')
         return redirect(url_for("admin_home"))
      elif request.method == "GET":
         form.username.data = user.username
         form.email.data = user.email
      image = url_for('static', filename=f'pictures/{user.image_file}')
      return render_template("edit_user.html", form=form, image=image, user=user)
      app.add_url_rule("/admin/user/<int:user_id>","edit_user", edit_user, methods=['GET','POST'])
```

**edit_user.py**

```
    {% extends "layout.html" %}
    {% block content %}
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row text-center">
            <!--Grid column-->
            <div class="col-sm1">
                <img class="rounded-circle z-depth-2" alt="" src="{{ image }}"
                data-holder-rendered="true" height="60" width="60">
              <p class="">{{ user.username }}</p>
              <p>{{ user.email }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="container">
     <form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('edit_user',user_id=user.id) }}" class="was-validated" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
         <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Account Info</legend>
         <div class="form-group">
             {{ form.email.label(class="form-control-label") }}
             {% if form.email.errors %}
                {{ form.email(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                   <div class="invalid-feedback">
                      {% for error in form.email.errors %}
                         {{ error }}
                      {% endfor %}
                   </div>
             {% else %}
               {{ form.email(class="form-control form-control-lg is-valid") }}
             {% endif %}
         </div>
        <div class="form-group">
           {{ form.image_file.label(class="form-control-label") }}
           {{ form.image_file(class="form-control-file")}}
           {% if form.image_file.errors %}
                {% for error in form.image_file.errors %}
                    <span class="text-danger">{{ error }}</span></br>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
        </div>
         <div class="form-group">
             {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}
         </div>
     </form>
    </div>
    {% endblock content %}
```

**forms.py**

```
    class UserUpdateForm(FlaskForm):
         username = StringField('Username',
                                        validators=[DataRequired(),
                                                    Length(min=2, max=20)])
         email = StringField('Email',
                                    validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
         image_file = FileField('Image File',
                                       validators=[DataRequired(), FileAllowed(['jpg', 'png'])]
         submit = SubmitField('Update')

         def validate_username(self, username):
           user = User.query.filter_by(username=username.data).first()
           if user:
                  raise ValidationError('This username already exists')

         def validate_email(self, email):
           user = User.query.filter_by(email=email.data).first()
           if user:
                  raise ValidationError('This email already exists')
```

**models.py**

```
 class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
        email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
        image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default.jpg')
        password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
        is_admin = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, default=0)
        leave_bank = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, default=20)
        created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow())
        updated_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow())
        leave_requests = db.relationship('LeaveRequest', backref="user_leave", lazy=True)
    
        def __repr__(self):
          return f"User('{self.username}','{self.email}','{self.image_file}','{self.is_admin}')"
```

Comment: Can you share your form codes with us? Thanks

Comment: Hello, its there Im using a package WTForms I have added everything there. file names are in between the asterisks i.e **file.py**

Comment: got it. Btw `session.commit` needed only at end, not after every model operation